# Getting top five rows from a populated table element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table (called `mytbl` - see below) consisting of 100 rows. From this table, I want to take only the first five rows (assume a user presses "Show Top Five")

This is what I have tried, however, the alert gives me 'empty'

```
var $updatedtable = $("#mytbl");
$updatedtable.empty();

for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) 
{
    $updatedtable.append(document.getElementById("mytbl").rows.item(i).innerHTML)
}

alert($updatedtable);
$updatedtable.appendTo( $( "#rbl" ) );
```

This was the code used to create the html page

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="rbl">
    <div id="rbldiv">
        <div class="bs-example voffset-10px">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputText" style="float:left;margin-right:5px;">Show top </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-normal" id="ben-count-set" placeholder="100">                     
                    </div>
                    <label for="inputText">  beneficiaries by cost increase</label>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <table id="mytbl" class="table table-striped table-hover"></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, if, after I successfully manage to get the top five and `appendTo` `rbl` which has `mytbl`, won't this get overwritten? If later the user wants to See Top 30, aren't the values gone? How can I take care of this?

**EDIT:**
I was able to get the display of the top rows thanks to charlietfl and Tatermelon. But my rows get sliced off, and I haven't completely understood how to handle a case where user selects top 10 first and then top 11.

This is what I have tried.
In the function where I'm making the (entire) table for the first time, I saved the table as follows

```
function makeTable() {
//code to make table rbltbl
//code to make table rbltbl
//code to make table rbltbl
//code to make table rbltbl

//below line saves the table to $rows, so I can use it inside the click function below
$rows = $('#rbltbl tr').clone();
}
```

This is my function. Assume 'ben-count-set' is the number of values, the user wants to see. I think I should change var $table to read from $rows instead of rbltbl. But $rows gives empty here.

```
$("#ben-count-submit").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("clicked on the update button");

      var reqcount = document.getElementById('ben-count-set').value;
        var $table = $("#rbltbl");

    var $mystring = '#rbltbl tr:gt('+parseInt(reqcount)+')';
    $($mystring).remove();
    console.log($mystring);
        $table.appendTo( $( "#rbl" ) );
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: of course it alerts empty, you first run empty() and do something when table is emty already)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of the first 5 rows can get it right in a jQuery object using several different selectors

```
$('#mytbl tr:lt(5)');
```

You can can cache all the rows into a variable and still have access to them later regardless of what you do to the table...just clone them

```
var $rows = $('#mytbl tr').clone();
```

Want to remove all but top 5

```
$('#mytbl tr:gt(4)').remove();
```

then change out for another selection of rows clone the clone, filter them and insert

```
 $('#mytbl').html( $rows.clone().slice(5, 10) );
```

Comment: I was able to get the top five, but I wasn't able to do the clone part. Please can you see my edit above.

Comment: doesn't look like you ever call `makeTable()`. Your code is not really very comprehensive...make a simple demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have edited above with a bit more explanation. Is that more helpful? In the mean time, I'll try to work on a jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, then you can use the :lt selector:

```
var $firstRows = $('#mytbl').find('tr:lt(5)');
```

Then, you can clone them to append in your new table so that they will not be removed from your original table:

```
$( "#rbl" ).append($firstRows.clone());
```

Comment: I don't think `children` will work right on table, cause of `tbody`, you can use `find` here or even better merge them `$('#mytble tr:lt(5)')`